# ImportError with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I found tutorial about work with GUI in python tkinter
then I try to learn it from w3school, I copied the sample code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter .ttk import *

root = Tk()
label = Label(root, text="Hello world Tkinket GUI Example ")
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

So, I google how to install tkinter on ubuntu.
I used:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-tk python3-tk tk-dev
$ sudo apt-get install python-tk             
$ pip install tk
```

It's seem it was successfully but I was wrong..

I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GotdE.png)

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: The name of your file is `tkinter.py`. When you use `from tkinter import *` it thinks you're trying to `import` from your file, not the stdlib module.

Comment: actually, I changed the name of file and it fixed... 
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally what you want is

```
import tkinter as tk  # 'as tk' isn't required, but it's common practice
from tkinter import ttk  # though you aren't using any ttk widgets at the moment...
```

I know star imports have a certain appeal, but they can lead to namespace pollution which is a huge headache!

For example lets say I've done the following:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()
label = Label(root, text='Hello!')
```

is `Label` a tkinter widget or a ttk widget?
Conversely...

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
label = ttk.Label(root)
```

Here, it's clear that `label` is a ttk widget.
Now everything is namespaced appropriately, and everyone's happy!

Comment: From the screenshot, OP's file name is `tkinter.py` which is the actual cause of the problem.

Comment: @Axe319 I have to agree, good catch! I'm gonna leave this up as a 'best practice' sort of thing

Comment: "_is `Label` a tkinter widget or a ttk widget? I don't know, and the interpreter doesn't either!_", the `Label` is overwritten with whatever is inside the last import, so technically the interpreter does know, right?

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria That's a fair point! I'll clarify that bit

Answer (score 1):

I believe you only need to use: `from tkinter import *`

I'd say get rid of the: `from tkinter .ttk import *`

Comment: The error was caused by the first `import` which occurred because of OP's file name, `tkinter.py`.

Comment: He/She is not using tttk. That could be comment out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just remove the line: `from tkinter .ttk import *`
I don't think you need that line to run this code.